single-value complex property with optional attribute deserialization
I'm dealing with XML deserialization using Jackson.
the xml data:
  <Coordinate>
            <Source>Network</Source>
            <Provider Name="Android 11.0">Vodafone</Provider>
    ...

<NameAndAddress>
            <Source>Phonebook</Source>
            <Provider>Virgin Media</Provider>
   ...

Java class to describe that Provider:
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Provider")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProviderDto {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    String name;

    @JacksonXmlText
    String value;
}

that Provider class is part of abstract class, as you may have noticed, the <Provider.. element is part of coordinate / location parent tag.
in it's abstract parent is added like:
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Provider")
    ProviderDto provider;

All works as long as I have <Provider Name="Android 11.0">Vodafone</Provider> in both 'Coordinate' and 'NameAndAddress'.
When I have xml the way I'm showing here it fails with:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'Provider' (expected type: [simple type, class ...: argument type mismatch

I think it's because Jackson thinks when it is single value 'property' it should be simple type -> string. But I need to have the ability to have name as an attribute too.
any suggestions?
thanks!
